# Can't copy files from MacOS to iCloud due to 'disk full' but iCloud has lots of free space

Tags: macos, icloud, finder

I keep trying to copy the folder from the local hard drive on the iMac across to icloud in Finder and it works for a while then says the 'disk is full'. This cannot be so as in finder it tells me that I have 136gb of free space and the folder I am trying to copy is only 1gb or so.

Why is it telling me that the 'disk is full'?

Comment: wow, you have a paid plan with iCloud with 136B space on it ? and you pay $50 a Year for it.

Comment: that's the free space that's left - it's 250gb and it costs less than 50$/year